# Using an inner join with subqueries in an update syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use a inner join with an update statement with a subquery ... can you help me out with the sytax please --- and also how do you use the AS clause for alias in sql server???
the following is what i am trying to do :

```
Update Table1 
inner join table2
set table1.value1 = (select table2.value1 where table1.value 1 ....)
```

any idea??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to use a subquery to perform the UPDATE you can do it this way:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.value = t2.value
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT id, value
    FROM table2
) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: I think you meant `SET t1.value` otherwise you'll get the error "The multi-part identifier "table1.value" could not be bound"

Answer (score 3):

One way is to alias the table:

```
update t1
set    table1.value1 = t2.value1
from   table1 as t1
join   table2 as t2
on     t1.id = t2.t1_id
```

Comment: What if you needed a subquery in there to determine value for table1.value1 ??? = (select ??)

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
UPDATE table1 SET t1.value1 = t2.value2 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t1.field1 = t2.field2
```

Comment: That's MySQL syntax, the question is for SQL Server

Comment: @Andomar: yes, thanks, I realized it too late and edited my answer. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT id, value
        FROM table2
    ) t2 USING(id)
SET t1.value = t2.value
```