# SQL - Similar Update Queries Produce Varying Results

Tags: sql

I am super new to SQL and have two queries I think should produce the same output but they don't. Can someone figure out the difference between them?

The input table for this simple example has two columns, `letter` and `extra`. The data in the first column is a random letter from the list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` and `extra` should not matter (I think?). These are the queries:

```
update 
    tbl
set
    extra = letter;
```

and:

```
update 
    tbl
set
    extra = (select
        letter
        from tbl);
```

The resulting tables these produce are:

```
e|e
e|e
c|c
e|e
b|b
...
```

and:

```
e|e
e|e
c|e
e|e
b|e
...
```

respectively.

I expect the first output for both queries, how come the second one turns out as it does?

EDIT:

The reason I ask this question is because what I want to do is a bit more involved than this simple example and I believe I need the subquery. I am trying to add a kind of normalisation column, like this:

```
update 
    tbl
set
    extra = 1 / (select 
        norm
        from 
            tbl
        INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT 
                letter, count(*) as norm
            FROM 
                tbl
            GROUP BY letter) as tmp
        ON
            tbl.letter = tmp.letter);
```

Alas, this obviously doesn't work because of the above.

Comment: Can't have the same output: in the second query you assign a value taken from a query asking for letters from the table. Now you get several letters and probably the first is used to update your column! With the 1st query you get the letter within the very same row of extra, so this works as expected.

Comment: What database do you use ?

Comment: @Marco But shouldn't the subquery return an entire column of values rather than a single one? The problem is that, in reality, I want to put something more advanced in the subquery and I don't think I can just put it straight after the equals sign. My subquery contains a `GROUP BY`, a `SUM` and an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @VBoka I'm just 'bugtesting in https://www.mycompiler.io/new/sql for the moment. Eventually I hope to migrate this into QuickSight where I think they are using a Redshift/Amazon SQL.

Comment: I ask because some databases will return the result you are talking about: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e48cf1b647e8728f5b315316dd2010c6 but others will tell you that you are doing something wrong because the second query is not ok. The subquery in the second query is returning too many values which I believe makes a much more logic because you never said you want the first column value to be returned in that subquery: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e48cf1b647e8728f5b315316dd2010c6

Comment: @VBoka How does it return too many values? Seems to me it should be returning one for every row?

Comment: @IvarEriksson where do you tell him to return ONE for EVERY ROW in this statement: select letter from tbl ? You tell him give me letter from tbl. Letter from tbl is e, c, b . Which one do you want ?

Comment: @VBoka Well, I figured it would, similar to the first example, map the first element to the first row and so forth, but obviously I am wrong.

Comment: Your start assumption is wrong. You have to think like the database. First you select one row where letter is "e"  and extra is null . set extra to a value of letter... No problem right ? That is what you do in your first query but you have to understand you move row per row...

Then in your second query you select one row where letter is "e"  and extra is null and you tell the database to go and get all the letters from that same table and put them in column extra. You tell this to the database in a special query called subquery.

Comment: @VBoka Makes perfect sense, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193487/using-an-inner-join-with-subqueries-in-an-update-syntax

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Close, I just figured it out myself though. The solution was indeed to use the UPDATE JOIN syntax but for PostgreSQL in my case.

Answer (score 1):

What your first query is saying:

```
Set the value of extra to the value of letter in the same row.
```

What the second query is saying:

```
Pick a value from the column "letter" in the table, and update every row in the table to have the column 'extra' contain that value.
```

They are different instructions, so you get different results.

Comment: Hmm, I can see that that's what's happening but it's not what I was expecting. If I want to make a more advanced subquery how would I go about assigning the result of the subquery to every row? More specifically, I want `extra` in every row to equal `1 / COUNT(this rows letter)`. So, the count counts the number of occurrences of every letter in the entire table and assigns the reciprocal of the different counts to the rows with the corresponding letters.